# Webpack - Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'PT'

Tags: typescript, webpack, tsconfig

I hope that someone can help me to understand this error.
I have two typescript project:

1. ProjectTemplate
2. Game

They are two very simple projects because I am taking my first steps with typescript and webpack.

In my ProjectTemplate (is located in this path: "C:\personale\Typescript\ProjectTemplate") project i have three files .ts:

Reel.ts

```
export class Reel {
public id:number;
constructor(idReel:number){
    this.id=idReel;
}

changeReelId(value:number){
    this.id=value;
}
```

}

Reels.ts

```
import { Reel } from "./Reel";

export class Reels {
    private reels:Array<Reel>=new Array();
    constructor(numberReels:number){
        if(numberReels>0){
            for(let i:number=0;1<numberReels; i++){
                let reel=new Reel(i);
                this.reels.push(reel);
            }
        }
    }

    printReel(){
        if(this.reels.length>0){
            this.reels.forEach(function (reel:Reel) {
                reel.changeReelId(1);
                console.log(reel.id);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Index.ts

```
import { Reels } from './Reels';

export class Index {
    constructor(){
        const reels:Reels= new Reels(6);
        reels.printReel();
    }

    callMirco(){
        console.log(this);
    }
}
```

this is my tsconfig.json for ProjectTemplate

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    "declaration": true,                      /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    "sourceMap": true,                        /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    "outDir": "dist/compiled/",                         /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  }
}
```

and this is my webpack.config.js for ProjectTemplate

```
const path = require('path');
const DtsBundleWebpack = require('dts-bundle-webpack')

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.ts",
    output: {
        filename: "ProjectTemplate.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/build')
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".js"]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{ test: /\.ts$/, loader: "ts-loader" }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new DtsBundleWebpack({
            name: 'ProjectTemplate',
            main: 'dist/compiled/**/*.d.ts',
            out: '../build/ProjectTemplate.d.ts',
            outputAsModuleFolder: true,
        })
    ]
}
```

In my Game (is located in this path: "C:\personale\Typescript\Game") project only one project Index.ts:

```
import {Reel} from "PT";
const r = new Reel(9);
console.log(r);
```

This is my tsconfig.json for Game project:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    "declaration": true,                      /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    "sourceMap": true,                        /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    "outDir": "build",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */

    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
     "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
     "paths": {
       "PT": ["../ProjectTemplate/dist/build/ProjectTemplate.d.ts"]
     },                                       /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  }
}
```

This is my webpack.config.js for Game project

```
const path = require('path');
const DtsBundleWebpack = require('dts-bundle-webpack')

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.ts",
    output: {
        filename: "main.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".js"],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{ test: /\.ts$/, loader: "ts-loader" }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new DtsBundleWebpack({
            name: 'Game',
            main: 'build/@types/**/*.d.ts',
            outputAsModuleFolder: true,
        })
    ]
}
```

and this is my index.html in my Game Project

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Game</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Test game </h1>
<script type="application/javascript" src="../ProjectTemplate/dist/ProjectTemplate.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="./build/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is when I try to run webpack build on my Game project I get this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'PT' in 'C:\personale\Typescript\Game\src'
 @ ./src/index.js 3:11-24
```

I think that I'm missing something in my webpack.config or tsconfig.

Which is way to load PT (ProjectTemplate) module in my game project?

Answer (score 0):

Webpack and typescript working separetely, webpack doesn't know about ts and ts doesn't know about webpack.
So in this sutuation you told to ts what 'PT' is (via paths), but you didn't do that for webpack.
Please add these lines to the webpack configuration at the root level

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    PT: path.resolve(__dirname, '../ProjectTemplate')
  }
}
```

Also, you are not exporting Reel class directly, so when importing you should use

```
import {Reel} from 'PT/Reel'
import {Reels} from 'PT/Reels'
import {Index} from 'PT/Index'
```

Comment: I try to add in my webpack.config.js of my Game Project this:
....
 resolve: {
        extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".js", ".d.ts"],
        alias: {
            PT: path.resolve(__dirname, '../ProjectTemplate')
        }
    },
...

but i have same error

Comment: @user3790694 please try change tsconfig from 
"paths": {
       "PT": ["../ProjectTemplate/dist/build/ProjectTemplate.d.ts"]
     }, 
to

"paths": {
       "PT": ["../ProjectTemplate"]
     },

and then test it with code in your Game file index.ts
`
const {Reel} = require('PT/Reel');
console.log('>>>', Reel)
`